# How to get itemView groupie recycler view

Tags: android, kotlin

I am using Groupie like this:

```
GroupAdapter adapter = new GroupAdapter();
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

I want to get itemView at particular position from the recycler, but I don't know how to do that with groupie. Please advise, Thanks!

Comment: Please provide us some code/logic that you have done so far. This is not a "make us a code" service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am so sorry that i forgot ViewDataBinding supported method "getRoot" which return the itemview at the position

Answer (score 0):

pass interface instance to adapter and in adapter onbindviewholder,on view click,get the position .

Answer (score 0):

```
class A implements Iabc{

GroupAdapter adapter=GroupAdapter(this,List<String>)
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

override getData(String a)
{
//gets particular position string val
}
}

interface Iabc{

getData(String a)

}


in adapter :

view.setOnClicklistener(iabc.getData(stringlist[position]))
```